# retrofit stopped working and always throws error "Unable to create converter"

Tags: android, retrofit2

I managed to get retrofit2 to work for a while. I used it with @POST and @GET successfully.

```
@POST("incidents")
Call<CallbackRequest> sendCallbackReport(@Body CallbackRequest callbackRequest, @Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("device_id") String deviceId);
@GET("articles")
Call<Articles> getArticles(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

But now it stopped working by reason of a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for...`

I have no idea what has changed in my project so it suddenly stops working. My configuration looks like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

}

Using it:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_V1)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

I meanwhile could narrow it done to a certain POST request:

```
@POST("incidents")
Call<GeneralRequest> sendGeneralRequest(@Body GeneralRequest generalRequest, @Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("device_id") String deviceId);
```

With the corresponding model:

```
public class GeneralRequest extends BaseRequest  {

private String subject;

private String notes;
private int serviceId;

public GeneralRequest(String company, String name, String phone, String email, String subject, String notes, int serviceId, int companyId, boolean emailNotification) {
    super(company, name, phone, email, companyId, notes, emailNotification);
    this.subject = subject;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.serviceId = serviceId;

    HashMap<String,Object> incident = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    incident.put("type","GeneralRequest");
    this.setIncident(incident);
}

public GeneralRequest(String company, String name, String phone, String email, String subject, String notes, int companyId, boolean emailNotification) {
    super(company, name, phone, email, companyId, notes, emailNotification);
    this.subject = subject;
    this.notes = notes;

    HashMap<String,Object> incident = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    incident.put("type","GeneralRequest");
    this.setIncident(incident);
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return notes;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.notes = message;
}

public int getServiceId() {
    return serviceId;
}

public void setServiceId(int serviceId) {
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
}
```

What could possibly go wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: would clean build help? everything looks right to me!!

Comment: btw in post request it should be @ Field or @ Query

Comment: I tried a clean and build a couple of times, but it doesn't help.

Comment: just a side note. I don't think you need `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`. the Gson library is already included in retrofit's converter-gson